# how to show the contents of a div only in the print file?

Tags: javascript, printing

watch my code below. I have a content in a DIV that can be printed when the "PRINT" button is clicked. It's working fine, however I need this div (and its contents) to be hidden from the site page and only shown in the print file. Do you suggest anything to me?

```js
    function printDiv(printThis) {
         var printContents = document.getElementById(printThis).innerHTML;
         var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;
         document.body.innerHTML = printContents;
         window.print();
         document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
    }
```

```html
<div id="printThis">
    content
    </div>
    <input type="button" onclick="printDiv('printThis')" value="PRINT" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use css `@media print`

This will hide all body elements and show only the div `#printThis` and all its children.

```
@media print {
    body * {
        visibility: hidden;
    }

    #printThis,  #printThis * {
        visibility: visible;
    }

    #printThis {
        width : 100%;
        height : auto;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
    }
}
```

js (No need to modify/hide elements. CSS will handle it)

```
function printDiv( printThis ) {
    window.print();
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="printThis">
    content
</div>
<input type="button" onclick="printDiv('printThis')" value="PRINT" />
```

Comment: worked cool! I knew this but I thought it was not going to work, that the file would go blank. Thank you!

Comment: Happy to help @ThiagoSoubra

Comment: Perfect! Thank u very much!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bootstrap you can just use a simple bootstrap class to hide or show a content in Print

```
<div class="hidden-print">content for non print</div>

<div class="visible-print">content for print only</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

its easy with bootstrap. first hide the div with the bootstrap class `hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-lg hidden-xs` them make it visible with the `visible-print class
edit your html to

`<div id="printThis" class="visible-print">
content
</div>
<input type="button" onclick="printDiv('printThis')" value="PRINT" />`